# Set property value with TypInfo routine

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe6

Assign dataset field values to properties performed by the following method :

```
var
  lvRuntimeContext: TRttiContext;
  lvRuntimeType: TRttiType;
  lvProp: TRttiProperty;
  lvAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  lvCol: EntityColumnAttrib;
begin

  if DataAccess.DataSet.Active then
  begin
    lvRuntimeContext := TRttiContext.Create;

    try
      lvRuntimeType := lvRuntimeContext.GetType(EntityColumnClassType);

      for lvProp in lvRuntimeType.GetProperties do
        for lvAttr in lvProp.GetAttributes do
          if lvAttr is EntityColumnAttrib then
          begin
            lvCol := (lvAttr as EntityColumnAttrib);

            if lvCol.InCurrentTable then
              case lvCol.FieldType of
                ftBytes: begin

                end;

                ftDateTime: lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<TDateTime>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsDateTime));
              else
                lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<Variant>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsVariant));
              end;

          end;
    finally
      lvRuntimeContext.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

In one of my classes there is a property of type **TMemoryStream** and I want to assign value from DataSet field(SQL Server: **binary** type) to it, How can I do this with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DataSet's `CreateBlobStream()` method to get a read-only `TStream` for the desired `TField`, do whatever you need with it, and then free it when finished.

If possible, you should change your property to accept any general `TStream`, not just `TMemoryStream` specifically.  That way, you can assign the blob `TStream` as-is directly to your property via RTTI (`TValue` can be implicitly created from any `TObject` pointer):

```
var
  lvRuntimeContext: TRttiContext;
  lvRuntimeType: TRttiType;
  lvProp: TRttiProperty;
  lvAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  lvCol: EntityColumnAttrib;
  lStrm: TStream;
begin    
  if DataAccess.DataSet.Active then
  begin
    lvRuntimeContext := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      lvRuntimeType := lvRuntimeContext.GetType(EntityColumnClassType);

      for lvProp in lvRuntimeType.GetProperties do
      begin
        for lvAttr in lvProp.GetAttributes do
        begin
          if lvAttr is EntityColumnAttrib then
          begin
            lvCol := (lvAttr as EntityColumnAttrib);

            if lvCol.InCurrentTable then
            begin
              case lvCol.FieldType of
                ftBytes: begin
                  lStrm := DataAccess.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName), bmRead);
                  try
                    lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, lStrm);
                  finally
                    lStrm.Free;
                  end;
                end;

                ftDateTime: begin
                  lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<TDateTime>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsDateTime));
                end;
              else
                lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<Variant>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsVariant));
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      lvRuntimeContext.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If the property must continue using `TMemoryStream` only, then you will have to create a temporary `TMemoryStream` object, copy the blob data into it (you can use `TStream.CopyFrom()` for that), and then assign it to the property:

```
var
  lvRuntimeContext: TRttiContext;
  lvRuntimeType: TRttiType;
  lvProp: TRttiProperty;
  lvAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  lvCol: EntityColumnAttrib;
  lBlobStrm: TStream;
  lMemStrm: TMemoryStream;
begin    
  if DataAccess.DataSet.Active then
  begin
    lvRuntimeContext := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      lvRuntimeType := lvRuntimeContext.GetType(EntityColumnClassType);

      for lvProp in lvRuntimeType.GetProperties do
      begin
        for lvAttr in lvProp.GetAttributes do
        begin
          if lvAttr is EntityColumnAttrib then
          begin
            lvCol := (lvAttr as EntityColumnAttrib);

            if lvCol.InCurrentTable then
            begin
              case lvCol.FieldType of
                ftBytes: begin
                  lMemStrm := TMemoryStream.Create;
                  try
                    lBlobStrm := DataAccess.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName), bmRead);
                    try
                      lMemStrm.CopyFrom(lBlobStrm, 0);
                    finally
                      lBlobStrm.Free;
                    end;
                    lMemStrm.Position := 0;
                    lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, lMemStrm);
                  finally
                    lMemStrm.Free;
                  end;
                end;

                ftDateTime: begin
                  lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<TDateTime>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsDateTime));
                end;
              else
                lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, TValue.From<Variant>(DataAccess.DataSet.FieldByName(lvCol.FieldName).AsVariant));
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      lvRuntimeContext.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy,
How to do the second solution via RTTI?

Comment: I have added some examples.

Comment: I've used the second method but the following error message is raised : raised exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'.

Comment: On which line exactly?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: in this line :
   lvProp.SetValue(ASystemColumns, lMemStrm);

Comment: It is my fault, The error due to incorrect definition of the property type, thanks Remy.